# Add capability to a role , so user is only able to view his own posts

Tags: capabilities, user-roles

I have created a user role `vendor`. Right now i am able to give the capabilities to the users,  to be able to only edit,delete etc

But then the user sees all the posts irrespective of who is the owner of the post.

But I was wondering can i somehow add capability to role`vendor` so that user is only able to see his posts only...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to remove capability `edit_others_posts` if assigned to vendor role.

Then use the code snippet given below:

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set('author', $user_ID );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Above code allows any users with the capability to edit other’s posts to view all posts. Where as users having role Vendor will only see their own posts.

For more customization you can use 'User Role Editor' plugin.